# extract cell volume from vtk

Tags: python, numpy, vtk, post-processing

I have some CFD results coming from an existing solver (nektar++) ans I would like to do some post-processing in Python. 
I need to extract the field (u,v,p) and the cell volume for every cell.

I managed to extract the fields into numpy arrays with this code:

```
import vtk
import vtk.util.numpy_support as VN
import numpy as np

filename = "t_2.vtk"

reader = vtk.vtkUnstructuredGridReader()
reader.ReadAllScalarsOn()
reader.ReadAllVectorsOn()
reader.SetFileName(filename)
reader.Update()

num_points = reader.GetOutput().GetNumberOfPoints()

p = VN.vtk_to_numpy(reader.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetScalars('p'))
u = VN.vtk_to_numpy(reader.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetVectors('u'))
v = VN.vtk_to_numpy(reader.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetVectors('v'))

P = vtk_to_numpy(p)
U = vtk_to_numpy(u)
V = vtk_to_numpy(v)
```

However I don't understand if there is a way or not (maybe the cell volume information is not in the output) to know also the value of the cell volume.

I guess that the right instruction should be something like:

```
Vol = VN.vtk_to_numpy(reader.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetScalars('Volume'))
```

Is there someone that has faced/is facing the same issue?

Thank you very much for your help.

Cheers,
Riccardo

Answer (score 1):

Have you managed to book any progress on this issue?  I am really amazed there is no easy solution to this question. It seemed really easy. However, I did not manage to do it.

I am using OpenFOAM and found a workaround. It does not help you, but hopefully someone else who uses OpenFOAM finds this answer helpful. You can use postprocess to write out the cell volumes. When you include them in the fields section of 'foamToVTK', you can read it in python in the same way you would read the pressure.

```
runApplication postProcess -func writeCellVolumes
runApplication foamToVTK -fields '(U p V)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`vtkMeshQuality`](https://www.vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkMeshQuality.html#details). It supports several volumetric cell types. See [here](https://lorensen.github.io/VTKExamples/site/Cxx/PolyData/MeshQuality) an example how to use it. In this example, you could try to use `SetTetQualityMeasureToVolume` (or alike) instead of `SetTriangleQualityMeasureToArea()`.